# Add Lines To Google Earth Using KML

Tags: kml, google-earth

So, basically, I'm trying to figure out a way that I can draw lines (say, representing the flight path of an RC plane or something) onto Google Earth using KML.  Here's the kicker though: I want to give it an initial location, and then check somewhere to see where to continue drawing the line to, draw the line, and leave it be.  Once it's done, I could then move it around.

Ex:

1. Starts at a point A in google Earth
2. Checks File XYZ.kml on //someserver
3. XYZ.kml has updated coordinates to draw to
4. Google Earth pulls in those coordinates and extends the line
5. Repeat 2->4 until complete
6. View completed flight path from 3rd person.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?  It seems like it can change the location of a model or something in this fashion, but you would have to watch it first person.  I haven't been able to figure out how to get this particular functionality to come out right.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet? I am not 100% sure what you mean by starting at a point and then checking KML. And example of what you have tried might help. Also, is this within Google Earth or the plugin. I just want to clarify as I have no experience which what programmatic control you have in the GE app, but if the plugin I might be able to help.

Comment: I must admit that I haven't tried much of anything yet beyond computationally creating some FlyTo stuff with cameras.  Which is great, but it sadly doesn't solve the problem I want it to solve.  This should be within Google Earth.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to approach what you are asking in the GE app. Hopefully one of the GE experts will have insight.

Comment: It's weird because it seems like it should be pretty easy; using KML Paths (using the <LineString>).  But from what I can tell, you can't maintain existing LineString and add new Linestrings using the <Update> mechanic?  Or am I just misinterpreting the documentation?

Comment: You can achieve (I think) something like you are asking with Update, but it is part of the `NetworkLinkControl` features to reload (and possibly modify) the KML. (I think the only way to have this happen is when the `NetworkLinkControl` element times out / expires). I have never played with this, but I am pretty sure you could not make it execute on a click / whatever you mean by starts on point A. This said - I have read about it only, not used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few ways of doing this, here is just 2.

1. Create a [LineString](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestring) via a [networkLink](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink) and then use the [Update](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#update) feature to update your LineString (ie replace with new version)
2. Create a LineString and then use `.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt()` to build upon it.

Edit: Sorry, as pointed out in comments, Option 2 is for GE Plug-in, not standalone version

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496426/issue-using-networklinkcontrol-for-updates-in-ge-plugin) for some help on using option #1

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029057/how-to-remove-a-linestring-which-is-added-part-by-part-to-ge-in-one-go) for more info on option #2

Comment: I think your option 1 has a good chance of meeting most of what he is asking (except for the on-click component he alludes to) as discussed in the comments. For Option 2 I know you can do this for the GE Plugin, but does something like this exist for the GE App?

Comment: You are right, edited answer. Also there is no onClick feature with the standalone AFAIK.

Comment: It is the assumption I was making around the requirement: `Starts at a point A in google Earth.` But I am still not clear on the actual use case of the whole thing. Basically I think he is stuck with the solution in Option 1 if using the App. And even that I would want to test to be certain it functions the way I expect in the plugin... Hopefully he will post results.

Comment: Yes, so I've been working on Option #1 there.  And I'm a bit stuck on something.  The SO question you linked to seems to have quite a few files listed.  Is this necessary?  It seems like I should just need two KML files.  One would have the <NetworkLinkControl> and <Update> stuff, and the other would be the file that points to on the server, which has the <LineStyle> stuff to create the lines.  Correct?

Comment: Refer to the answer and not the question. Yes, you only need 2 KML files. The first KML is your standard one that is loaded as normal. The second KML you load is a 'networkLink' and within that KML you have the <NetworkLinkControl> and <Update> stuff whose <targetHref> is the first KML file you loaded.

Comment: Forgot to post this sooner!  Managed to get everything working by Friday.  Option 1 worked great.  Thanks for all the help everyone.